# How to fix lines of axes overlapping imshow plot?

Tags: matplotlib, figure, imshow

When plotting matrices using matplotlib's `imshow` function the lines of the axes can overlap the actual plot, see the following minimal example (`matshow` is just a simple wrapper around `imshow`):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
ax.matshow(np.random.random((50, 50)), interpolation="none", cmap="Blues")
plt.savefig("example.png", dpi=300)
```

[image: matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow example with 50x50 random data]

I would expect every entry of the matrix to be represented by a square, but in the top row it is quite obvious that the axis is hiding a bit of the plot resulting in non-square entries. The same is happening for the last column. Since I want the complete matrix to be seen - every entry with the same importance - is there any way this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is just a visualisation issue. If I run your code and maximise the window, I do not see the overlapping you are talking about:
[image]
[image]

Otherwise, remove the spines but without hiding the ticks:

```py
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Reduce the thickness of the borders:
`[x.set_linewidth(0.3) for x in ax.spines.values()]`

The following is the exported image:

[image]

With `0.2` the exported image looks like this:
[image]

Comment: It is definitely not just a visualization issue. I edited the example to include the dpi I used to save the figure, but the problem is also occurring with vector graphics (which I unfortunately cannot upload here). I would prefer a solution that keeps the spines, but has them drawn _around_ the plot not over. Thanks for your suggestion, though!

Comment: I replied before you changed `show` to `savefig`. Now the question is clearer. I have edited my answer with another option. Now the borders are visible and the overlapping negligible.

Comment: That answer is a good one, for sure! I just feel like it should be possible to keep the width of the spines and just have them positioned slightly more outward. To be honest I am a bit surprised, that matplotlib is allowing this overlap in the first place.